# Salida inesperada al operar entre diferentes variables

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Estoy programando un algoritmo en c++ donde la estructura del problema es lógico-matemático y está de hecho bien estructurado, pero en el código no me da la respuesta que deseo, suele poner los resultados en 0 o resultados demasiado grandes 
Este es el código:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int
 main ()
{
int edadDaniel = 0 ;
float edadMaria =  4/3*edadDaniel;
float edadSara = 2/3*edadDaniel;
float edadMama = edadDaniel + edadSara + edadMaria;

cout << "Que edad tiene?" << endl;
cout << "Tengo 3 hijos, preguntele a Daniel su edad"<< endl;
cout << "Cual es tu edad, Daniel?" << endl;
cin >> edadDaniel;
cout << "La edad de Daniel es " << edadDaniel << endl;
cout << "La edad de María es "<< edadMaria << endl;
cout << "La edad de Sara es " << edadSara << endl;
cout << "La edad de la madre es " << edadMama << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: te falta el printf();

Answer (score 5):

> y está de hecho bien estructurado

... pero está tabulado de forma pésima, lo que hace que sea más dificil de leer y seguir:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  int edadDaniel = 0 ;
  float edadMaria =  4/3*edadDaniel;
  float edadSara = 2/3*edadDaniel;
  float edadMama = edadDaniel + edadSara + edadMaria;

  cout << "Que edad tiene?" << endl;
  cout << "Tengo 3 hijos, preguntele a Daniel su edad"<< endl;
  cout << "Cual es tu edad, Daniel?" << endl;
  cin >> edadDaniel;
  cout << "La edad de Daniel es " << edadDaniel << endl;
  cout << "La edad de María es "<< edadMaria << endl;
  cout << "La edad de Sara es " << edadSara << endl;
  cout << "La edad de la madre es " << edadMama << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> suele poner los resultados en 0 o resultados demasiado grandes

```
int edadDaniel = 0 ;
float edadMaria =  4/3*edadDaniel;
```

Lo raro es que no de 0:

```
4/3*0 = 0*0 = 0
```

Los cálculos no se desplazan en el tiempo, sino que se ejecutan en el mismo momento en el que los ubicas dentro del código.

Lo que tienes que hacer es pedirle al usuario los datos y después realizar los cálculos:

```
cout << "Que edad tiene?" << endl;
cout << "Tengo 3 hijos, preguntele a Daniel su edad"<< endl;
cout << "Cual es tu edad, Daniel?" << endl;
cin >> edadDaniel;

float edadMaria =  4/3*edadDaniel;
float edadSara = 2/3*edadDaniel;
float edadMama = edadDaniel + edadSara + edadMaria;
```

Y ya esta!!!! bueno, no, todavía sigue dando resultados extraños.

Ahora el resultado no es el esperado porque estás **dividiendo enteros** y los enteros **no tienen** decimales:

```
4/3 = 0
```

Lo solucionas convirtiendo uno de los dígitos a decimal:

```
float edadMaria =  4./3*edadDaniel;
//                  ^ 4. es equivalente a 4.0

float edadSara = 2/3.0*edadDaniel;
//                  ^ aquí convertimos el denominador
```

En cualquier caso no está de más agrupar las operaciones con paréntesis para evitar sustos. Porque dependiendo de la prioridad de cada operador el resultado podría cambiar:

```
edadDaniel = 10;

4 / 3 * 10 => (4 / 3) * 10 = 1.333 * 10 = 13.33
4 / 3 * 10 => 4 / (3 * 10) = 4 / 30 = 0.1333
```

Así que o te aprendes de memoria la prioridad de los diferentes operadores o te curas en saludo y usas paréntesis (que así además queda más claro y bonito):

```
float edadMaria =  (4./3)*edadDaniel;
float edadSara  = (2./3)*edadDaniel;
```